# Every order topology is regular (proof check)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, separation-axioms, order-topology

My proof:

Let $X$ be an space with the order topology, $x \in X$ and $F$ a closed set that does not contain $x$. Then, the set $X-F$ is an open set that contains $x$, hence there is an open set (basic) $(a,b)$ such that $x \in (a,b)\subseteq X-F$. Then $(a,b)$ and $(-\infty,a) \cup (b,\infty)$ are open disjoint sets that separate $x$ and $F$.

I am not sure because I've seen other proofs and they are much more complicated, like this one ([source](http://es.scribd.com/doc/75627148/325-HW-06#scribd)):

[image]

Besides, in that proof I don't understand when do they use the fact that a point is closed in a Hausdorff space. I also found that the last union is not disjoint, I double check that, but I may be missing something.

Comment: regular here means $T_1$ plus every closed set and point can be separated by disjoint open sets (so $T_3$). So $T_1$-ness, or even $T_2$-ness have to be shown as well. It's not used in the second part, but it is necessary for the property as defined in Munkres.

Comment: The last bit is a typo: it should say $V = V_1 \cap V_2$. $U = U_1 \cup U_2$ *is* correct. The extra checks are needed because the point $x$ could have a direct neighbour on either side, which necessitates a more cumbersome notation. Consider $x = 1$ and $A = \{2,3\}$ in the natural numbers, in the order topology e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thanks, my teacher defined regularity without $T_3$ and $T_3=\text{regular}+T_1$. But, even if I included the Hausdorff part, I don't quite get exactly what part is wrong with my proof to show that I can separate points and closed sets. I also have a bit of trouble understanding the naturals with that topology, I can not find a way to separate 1 and $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof wouldn't work as while your (a,b) could exist, there is nothing to say that a and b aren't in F. So your open set wouldn't necessarily contain F.